# Converting rows in pandas dataframe to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert rows in the foll. pandas dataframe to column headers:

```
                     transition          area
0                    A_to_B       -9.339710e+10
1                    B_to_C       2.135599e+02
```

result:

```
   A_to_B            B_to_C
0  -9.339710e+10     2.135599e+02
```

I tried using pivot table, but that does not seem to give the result I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with column `transition`, then transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), remove columns name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print df.set_index('transition').T.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
         A_to_B    B_to_C
0 -9.339710e+10  213.5599
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael. This works great on a windows machine, but surprisingly fails on mac os x (python 2.7.11 on both and latest pandas version). On Mac OS X, I get error: `TypeError: Must pass an index to rename`

Comment: my bad, the pandas version on mac os x was 0.17 and not 0.18. updated version and it works now

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.T

df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]

df = df.iloc[1:, :]
```

Comment: I think you need add `reset_index` and `rename_axis` to your code.