# Reshape rows to columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In pandas how to go from a:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['m', 'm', 'm', 's', 's', 's'],
                    'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
>>> a
   bar foo
0    1   m
1    2   m
2    3   m
3    4   s
4    5   s
5    6   s
```

to b:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'m': [1, 2, 3],
                    's': [4, 5, 6]})
>>> b
   m  s
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

I tried solutions in other answers, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38681821/reshape-pandas-dataframe-from-rows-to-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708567/converting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-to-columns) but none seemed to do what I want.

Basically, I want to swap rows with columns and drop the index, but how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a.set_index(
    [a.groupby('foo').cumcount(), 'foo']
).bar.unstack()
```

Comment: can you detail a bit what's going on? I looked at the GroupBy.cumcount() documentation, but it's somewhat cryptic.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of detail. I'm on my phone. The problem with the information you have is that you need to differentiate between the different values with the same foo value. Cumcount does exactly that by creating a 0, 1, and 2 for the first 3 and the same again for the second three. What's more is that it will work if they weren't both of size 3. Given the positions I set the index at, it is laid out perfectly for an unstack.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['m', 'm', 'm', 's', 's', 's'],
                    'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
a.pivot(columns='foo', values='bar').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))

foo    m    s
0    1.0  4.0
1    2.0  5.0
2    3.0  6.0
```